# Run a chord callback even if the main tasks fail

Tags: python, callback, celery, chord

Is it possible to run a [chord](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords) callback even if the main tasks failed?

I've created a chord which I added a bunch of tasks and registered a callback to it. My problem is that if one of the tasks fail, the callback is not triggered. But I would like the callback to be triggered either way.

I've tried to register the callback with si() ([immutability](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#immutability))

```
callback = tasks.run_delete_rule.si([timestamp])
header = [tasks.run_update_rule.s(i, timestamp) for i in item_ids]
result = chord(header)(callback)
```

I also tried to add the parameter `ignore_result=True` to both tasks decorator, but no success.

Comment: I am looking for this same solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the github issue [#1881](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1881) if the callback has the `link_error` option set, which takes a list of tasks names, then when a task of the chord fails the link_error tasks are going to be executed.

```
@task(name='super_task.good')
def good():
    return True

@task(name='super_task.raise_exception')
def raise_exception():
    raise ValueError('error')

@task(name='super_task.callback')
def callback(*args, **kwargs):
    logger.info('callback')
    logger.info(args)
    logger.info(kwargs)
    return 'finished'

@task(name='super_task.error_callback')
def error_callback(*args, **kwargs):
    logger.info('error_callback')
    logger.info(args)
    logger.info(kwargs)
    return 'error'

>>> c = chord(
        [raise_exception.s(), good.s(), raise_exception.s()], 
        callback.s().set(link_error=['super_task.error_callback'])
    )
>>> result = c()
```

This will execute the chord and in your celery log, you'll see the `raise_exception` task fail, and the execution of `error_callback` which will receive in it's args the task_id of `callback`.

At this point the value of `result` will contain the `AsyncResult`instance of `callback`, and because in a chord the errors propagate to the callback doing `result.get()` will raise the exception of the tasks and `result.traceback` gives you the traceback.

If you want to have a single callback, just pass the name of the chord callback to `link_error`

```
callback.s().set(link_error='super_task.callback')
```

**NOTE**

Another options it's to set `CELERY_CHORD_PROPAGATES = False` which will revert to the pre celery 3.1  behavior and always execute the callback.

But this is not a recommended approach because as you can find in the github issue [#1349](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1349)

> Celery 3.1 defines how chord errors are handled, the previous behavior was never documented
>   and more of an accident since it was never the intention to work that way.
>
> We couldn't change the behavior in a bugfix release so a setting had to be used instead,
>   but it was never the intention that someone would deliberately disable the new behavior.
>
> The new behavior is there to protect against this sort of issue happening, and the backward compatible setting may be removed. I suggest you find some other way to handle errors here (and I wouldn't mind a proposal if you can invent a nice api for it)

Comment: How would I get the result of the good task in error_callback?

Comment: @Carl I not 100% sure but I don't think you can. I think the only attributes you can get are the Exception and the Traceback of the task that failed. You can maybe use a data store if you need something specific to be retrieved later even if everything fails. We just needed it to send and email so I didn't play too much with that.

Comment: According to the accept code, I get error callback run, but the chord function still raise exception, not return value from the error callback...

Comment: How to pass parameter to the function of `link_error`?

Comment: I don't think you should attach link_error to the callback. link_error should be attached to the chord (task) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change manner how `link_error` is called. Instead of string reference, pass signature with arguments you want.

In example above, you can pass argument as following

```
c = chord(
    [raise_exception.s(), good.s(), raise_exception.s()], 
    callback.s().set(link_error=[error_callback.s(<arguments_here>)])
)
```

Just keep on mind, first argument will be `task_id` and further arguments will be those defined in signature.