# Celery - continue call back if group task fails(effective logging of task failures)

Tags: python, logging, celery

Using celery 4.4.2, I have a group of tasks that connects to remote devices and gathers data, when that is completed the results are collated then emailed with the callback task.

However if gathering the data of one of the remote devices fails, the call back also fails. I've read that using link_error should resolve this but I'm not sure if my implementation, I have executed the below but it still failed

```
    for device in device_ids:
        task_count +=1
        tasks.append(config_auth.s(device.id, device.hostname, device.get_scripts_ip()))

    callback = email_auth_results.s().set(link_error=error_handler.s())
    tasks = group(tasks)
    r = chord(tasks)(callback)

    return '{} tasks sent to queue'.format(task_count) 


@app.task
def error_handler(uuid):
    result = AsyncResult(uuid)
    exc = result.get(propagate=False)
    print('Task {0} raised exception: {1!r}\n{2!r}'.format(
          uuid, exc, result.traceback))
```

original error:

```
celery.exceptions.ChordError: Dependency 5ffc10c9-edc7-4b91-a660-08c372c60ab2 raised NetmikoTimeoutException('Connection to device timed-out')
```

I still want to log that a task failed so I can see the failures in flower, but I want to ignore the failures or append the results so they just say failure and I can see it in the email results

Thanks

Comment: Do not call .get() inside a task. Your error_handler needs to be refactored. The easiest way is to store the results temporarily in Redis (perhaps a different Redis DB) so that your error_handler can easily grab them, instead of calling .get()? Or simply pass the results to it, instead of task ID (bad idea if result is a big object - in this case use Redis or memcached)!

Comment: im not so bothered about the error, I will be able to see the errors in flower, I just want the chord to be able to continue on a failure, currently chord doesn't complete unless all tasks do. Thanks for your help

Comment: here all the colabrators are discussing the problem with chord error and there was no possible work around from the discussion. Finally what i can suggest you for the time being is used the latest version of celery may be they have fixed it. https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3317

Comment: one of the good implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355613/run-a-chord-callback-even-if-the-main-tasks-fail

Comment: I have a few suggestions if you comfortable in using some other things like external queues like rabbitmq for storing your call back messages etc.